# Stream Analytics Query UI portal: Unable to connect to input source at the moment

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I followed the link below, and created an input, like below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-tutorial-visualize-anomalies

The Test button in the red box confirms the connection is ok.
[image]

However, on the Query page, it shows error below:

> Unable to connect to input source at the moment. Please check if the
> input source is available and if it has not hit connection limits.

[image]

Below shows that the incoming messages are already in the event hub.

[image]

I tried using both Connection String and MI for the input, but am still getting the error.

I can send messages to and receive them from the event hub by following the link below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-standard-getstarted-send

Comment: Sometimes it takes a few minutes for the managed identity settings to propagate. Could you try again, giving it some times for that to happen?

Comment: To make sure there are records on the wire, you can sample data from an input source by using VS Code and the Azure Stream Analytics extension : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/visual-studio-code-local-run-live-input

Comment: Thank you again for your help. I will give it a go again, and come back once I have the result.

Answer (score 0):

> To test your query against a **specific time range** of incoming events, select **Select time range**.

[image]

You may checkout the [MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/363168/can39t-test-query-on-my-stream-analytics-job.html) thread addressing similar issue.

For more details, refer to [Test an Azure Stream Analytics job in the portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-test-query).